# Dynamic programming in CUDA: global memory allocations to exchange data with child kernels

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I have a the following code:

```
__global__ void interpolation(const double2* __restrict__ data, double2* __restrict__ result, const double* __restrict__ x, const double* __restrict__ y, const int N1, const int N2, int M)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    [...]        

    double phi_cap1, phi_cap2;

    if(i<M) {   

         for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {

              [calculate phi_cap1];

              for(int n=0; n<(2*K+1); n++) {

                 [calculate phi_cap2];

                 [calculate phi_cap=phi_cap1*phi_cap2];

                 [use phi_cap];

             }
    }

}

}
```

I would like to use Dynamic Programming on a Kepler K20 card to dispatch the processing of `phi_cap1` and `phi_cap2` in parallel to a bunch of threads to reduce the computation time. `K=6` in my code, so I'm launching a single block of `13x13` threads.

Following the CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide, I'm allocating a matrix `phi_cap` of `169` elements (formed by the products of `phi_cap1` and `phi_cap2`), needed to exchange the data with the child kernel, in *global memory*. Indeed, quoting the guide,

> As a general rule, all storage passed to a child kernel should be allocated explicitly from the global-memory heap.

I then ended-up with the following code

```
__global__ void interpolation(const double2* __restrict__ data, double2* __restrict__ result, const double* __restrict__ x, const double* __restrict__ y, const int N1, const int N2, int M)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    [...]   

    dim3 dimBlock(2*K+1,2*K+1); dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    if(i<M) {   

    double* phi_cap; cudaMalloc((void**)&phi_cap,sizeof(double)*(2*K+1)*(2*K+1));

    child_kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(cc_diff1,cc_diff2,phi_cap);

    for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {

        for(int n=0; n<(2*K+1); n++) {

                        [use phi_cap];

        }
    }

}
```

}

The problem is that the first routine takes `5ms` to run, while the second routine, even by commenting the `child_kernel` launch, takes `23ms`, with practically all the time spent in the `cudaMalloc` API.

Since in dynamic programming one would often need allocating memory space to exchange data with the child kernels, and the only solution seems to be global memory taking so much time, it seems to me that one serious bottleneck of the usefulness of dynamic programming is the data exchange, unless there is a way to circumvent the global memory allocation issue.

The question then is: *is there any workaround to the mentioned issue, namely, taking so much time when allocating global memory from within a kernel?*. Thanks

**SOLUTION PROPOSED IN THE COMMENTS**

*Allocate the required global memory from outside the parent kernel.* I have verified that allocating the required global memory from outside the parent kernel is *much* faster.

Comment: The question is pretty clear: anybody knows any workaround to this bottlneck? Please, carefully read the last sentence of the post.

Comment: @JackOLantern: When you post code, try to keep in mind that others have to read it in a roughly 100 column wide scroll box. The code is *very* difficult to read.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your comment. I edited my post by simplifying the code.

Comment: @JackOLantern: I wasn't suggesting you simplify it. I was suggesting you properly format it so that it didn't contain long lines, mismatched indentation and parentheses, etc. Now you have removed most of the important details while still leaving 188 character long lines in the posted code.....

Comment: @talonmies What I'm trying to say is that `cudaMalloc` takes much longer than the whole execution of the first code (i.e., that without dynamic programming), whatever it does. My feeling is that data exchange between partent and child kenels is a severe limitation for dynamic programming, due to the need to use global memory, unless someone could suggest a way to workaround this issue or unless the code is so compute bound to mask out the `cudaMalloc` time.

Comment: @JackOLantern When posting kernel code it is helpful to always specify expected values (or ranges) for the gridDim, blockDim and any constant. In your code you are calling cudaMalloc per thread. It may be significantly faster to call this per block or to allocate the memory before the host launch.

Comment: @JackOLantern You are calling cudaMalloc from each thread where i < M which means that you are making M cudaMalloc calls. The bigger M is the worse it is going to get.
Instead you could make a single cudaMalloc call from the first thread allocating M times the size that you used before (actually in your case you should allocate more, so each block is properly aligned). After that sync the threads and you can start your child kernels with correctly computed phi_cap address for each child kernel.

Comment: @JackOLantern Why bother with allocating memory from inside the kernel each time when you can allocate it once outside of the kernel and reuse it? That would be a lot quicker. If M is varies between kernel calls you could allocate as much as you would need for the biggest M.

Comment: @GregSmith Thank you very much to you and RoBiK. That was the answer I needed. Allocating the memory from outside the kernel is significantly faster. Anyway, by dispatching all the calculations to the child kernel it is also possible to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: @RoBiK Just as a notice. For my problem, I have found a solution fully avoiding global memory storage. The parent kernel performs just the scheduling of the work by the child kernel and all the work is performed by the child kernel. I have verified that when `M` is very large, then using dynamic programming becomes very convenient.

Comment: @RoBik Anyway, although pretty good working in my case, I see allocating the needed global memory from outside the parent kernel a limitation in two cases: 1) the number of launched threads is large and the required memory per thread is large, so the global memory capacity would not be enough to allocate all the required space in advance; 2) the threads have a time-varying computational load, in which case one would be forced to possibly allocate much more space than actually required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling cudaMalloc from each thread where i < M which means that you are making M cudaMalloc calls.

The bigger M is the worse it is going to get.

Instead you could make a single cudaMalloc call from the first thread of the block allocating M times the size that you used before (actually in your case you should allocate more, so each block is properly aligned). After that sync the threads and you can start your child kernels with correctly computed phi_cap address for each child kernel.

Alternatively (if your specific situation allows you to allocate enough memory that you can hold on to between the kernel calls) you could allocate the memory once outside of the kernel and reuse it. That would be a lot quicker. If M varies between kernel calls you could allocate as much as you would need for the biggest M.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a comment. The first solution could be convenient in problems with varying computational load, for example, when the amount of the global memory to be allocated is not known to the host side, but is calculated on the device side. For my particular problem, I would choose the second possibility.